# Simple tkinter application that choose a random string

Tags: python, beginner, tkinter

I am really new to programming, and I made this simple tkinter app in
python. Please tell me what can be improved and how to use classes
correctly in combination with tkinter.

[Github to clone if you want](https://github.com/apocalyps0/lol-random-game)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# ---------------------------------
# @author: apoc
# @version: 0.1
# ---------------------------------

# importing
from tkinter import *
import csv
from random import randint


class LRG(object):

    def __init__(self,master):

        # variables
        with open('data/champs.csv','r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            self.champ_list = list(reader)

        # layout
        self.randombutton = Button(master,text='Random',command=self.scan)
        self.infofield = Text(master,height=20,width=50)

        # layout
        self.randombutton.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=E,pady=2,padx=5)
        self.infofield.grid(row=1,columnspan=4,sticky=W,column=0,pady=4)

    def scan(self):

        self.infofield.delete('1.0',END)
        self.infofield.insert(END,self.champ_list[
            randint(0,len(self.champ_list))
            ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    LRG(master)
    master.title("LRG")
    master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Standards

Follow the PEP8 coding standard.  One violation that immediately is obvious is the lack of a space following a comma.  For example, `(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=2, padx=5)` is much easier to read.  Use `pylint` (or similar) to check your code style against the recommended standard.

## Import grouping

My personal preference is to keep `import ...` statements together, and `from ... import ...` statements together, not interleave them.

## Private class members

"Private" members should be prefixed with an underscore.  Such as `self._champ_list` and `def _scan(self):`.  This doesn't actually make them private, but some tools will use the leading underscore as a key to skip generating documentation, not offer the member name in autocomplete, etc.

## Remove useless members

`self.randombutton` is only used in the constructor; it could just be a local variable, instead of a member.

## Use correct comments

The `# layout` comment above the `Button` and `Text` construction is misleading; it is not doing any layout.

## Self documenting names

Use understandable names.  I have no idea what `LRG` is.  Good variable names go a long way towards creating self-documenting code.

## Use Doc-Strings

Add `"""doc-strings"""` for files, public classes, public members, and public functions.  Using `LRG` as a class name could be fine (in may be a common acronym at your company), but adding a doc-string for the class could spell out what the acronym stands for at least once.

## Avoid hard-coded information

You have hard-coded reading the `data/champs.csv` file into the constructor.  Consider making it more flexible, such as passing in a filename with that as a default.

```
class LRG:
    """Literal Random Generator"""

    def __init__(self, master, csv_filename="data/champs.csv"):
        # ...etc...
```

Or, move the reading of the data outside of the class, and pass the `champ_list` in as a constructor argument.